# How to run a group of tests sequentially?

Tags: haskell

I have **tasty** tests looking as:

```hs
myTests :: [TestTree]
myTests = [
    testCase "1" $ do ... assertBool ...
  , testCase "2" $ do ... assertBool ...
  , testCase "3" $ do ... assertBool ...
  , testCase "4" $ do ... assertBool ...
  ...
]
```

But the problem with them is that **some of them** (lets say, 3, 4) share some system resource which must be used in a "mutually exclusive" style (actually it's a file, but it could be something else). As I understood, the problem is that tests 1, 2, 3, 4, ... run in parallel.

So, I want to run tests 3, 4 sequentially. Others - in parallel. I am thinking about something like this:

```hs
  par = [...]
  seq = someMagic [...]
  myTests = par <> seq
```

What is `someMagic` function? I found `localOption @NumThreads 1 $ [...]` but it works with `TestTree` as its 2nd argument, not with a list of `TestTree`! How to do something like this?

- EDIT-1: I just found another idea: to use `testGroup` to "fold" them into one `TestGroup`.
- EDIT-2: Just tried `testGroup` - but I get the same problem about a busy resource.
- EDIT-3: Another idea is to use `after` to declare dependency

Comment: If your test uses the outside world it should be an `IO` action, you compose them like other `IO` actions to run them sequentially. That's the whole point of `IO`.

Comment: @cafce25 Ah, do you mean to executes such tests in one testCase? (sorry, I got you wrongly first time)

Comment: A test that relies on exclusive IO access to a resource will be inherently quite brittle. I'd suggest making as much of the program logic independent of those accesses and checking that in a test suite that can be evaluated in parallel. Then, put the (hopefully few) tests that require excluse access in a separate sequentially-run test suite where it's understood that it can fail unpredictably.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to declare explicit order (a dependency) between tests with [after](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tasty-1.4.3/docs/Test-Tasty.html#t:DependencyType) (and similar functions).

```hs
[
...
, testCase "testMyFunc: must fails" $ do
    ...

, after AllFinish "$NF ~ /testMyFunc/" $ testCase "anotherFunc: must work" $ do
    ...
...
]
```

Used expression is described in Tasty's [README](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tasty). So, if tests run in parallel, some of them can be ordered (sequential).